# dropdown menu with only 10 visible links

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am wondering if it is possible to make the dropdown menu only have 10 visible links, and the rest would be invisible. If it ain't possible, is it possible to make it so you can only se 10 and scroll down. Any suggestions?

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is the purpose of the invisible ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the height values of the first 10 items and set that manually in CSS or you can use Javascript count the first 10 items and add their heights together. As it is now they all have the same height so you could do `h*10` but if for some reason an item breaks to a second line your height would be off. I've updated your snipped.

I've updated the `myFunction` function. You'll notice I add the `show` class before calculating the height as `offsetHeight` will always return 0 if the parent is hidden.

### Hiding When Clicking off Button

We can handle this with the `blur` event. Rather than using an attribute for the event like the `onclick` we're going to handle this solely with JS.

### Returning to Top of Dropdown

In order to return to the top of the dropdown after you click out of the dropdown we need to use the `scrollTop` property. in `myFunction()` the last line we set `scrollTop = 0` on the `dropDown` element which scrolls us to the top!

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.dropbtn');

btn.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  var dd = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  if ( dd.classList.contains('show') ) {
    dd.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropdown'),
    items = dropDown.children,
    height = 0;
  dropDown.classList.toggle('show');
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    height += items[i].offsetHeight;
  }
  dropDown.style.height = height + 'px';
  dropDown.scrollTop = 0;
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var btn = document.querySelector('.dropbtn');

btn.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  var dd = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  if ( dd.classList.contains('show') ) {
    dd.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you could help me a little. #1 - When you press outside the dropsown it don't close. #2 - When you close the dropdown, and then pen it again, it don't start from the top of the list.

Comment: @AleksanderRanum I've updated the answer for your first question. As for the second not sure what you mean.

Comment: When you open the dropdown, you are at the top of the list, then you scroll down and then close the dropdown. When you then open the dropdown the next time, it still is at the same point an not at the top again. Hope this was a little bit clearer.

Comment: So I tried the the update to the answer, but it only works in the code snippet and not on my website

Comment: @AleksanderRanum I've updated my answer for the scroll position. As for why it isn't working on your site I can't really help you there. It works here, isn't using any 3rd part libraries, 'not working' is really vague.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: New answer:**

I misinterpreted the question. You can slightly modify your filter function to keep track of shown items (10) and then just call it once whenever you open the menu. This way you're showing max 10 items when opening the menu and when filtering. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d3kta5sw/

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    filterFunction();
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i,
        elementsToShow = 10,
        elementsShowing = 0;

    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 &&
            elementsShowing < elementsToShow) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
            elementsShowing++;
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

**Old Answer (only works for first 10 visible items):**

You can do this in pure css. Try adding the following, this will hide the 11th 'a' element and onwards:

```
.dropdown-content a:nth-of-type(n+11) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: It won't work, nth-of-type will conside all items, even hidden. So no. Not that simple.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I misinterpreted the question. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

**CSS option:**

```
.show{
    overflow:overlay: //to hide to the other elements
    height:200px; //to show desired number of elements
}
```

Better to use this element:

`.dropdown-content`